# PHP dynamic URL keeps adding/doubling the full path when i click a button on the site

Tags: redirect

I am running into an issue and I hope someone here can help. I have put together a dynamic URL manipulator that should just work out the path to the file being displayed, which it does and when I click a link, it should process the new link and replace the existing URL. The issue is that instead of replacing the URL with the new url path, it adds it to the end of the existing URL which is why it does not work. an example is as follows:
https://localhost/home/main/localhost/home/main/pages/about

the part from the second localhost... should replace the first url path but it adds to it and therefore it does not work. the code for this is as follows:

```
class Core {
    protected $currentController = 'Pages';
    protected $currentMethod = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct(){
      //print_r($this->getUrl());

      $url = $this->getUrl();

      if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]). '.php')){
         $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
         unset($url[0]);
       }

    
        require_once '../app/controllers/'. $this->currentController . '.php';

      $this->currentController = new $this->currentController;

      if(isset($url[1])){
         if(method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])){
         $this->currentMethod = $url[1];
         unset($url[1]);
      }
     }

  
        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];
      call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod], $this->params);
    }

    public function getUrl(){
      if(isset($_GET['url'])){
        $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
        $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        return $url;
      }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi anyone who cares to know the solution to this, or have a similar issue and is looking to find a solution.

I found out that the issue was with the htaccess file which did not have the full root of the home page.

I had entered
RewriteBase /main/public
my app is in a subfolder called home so after updating it to the following, it works like a charm.
RewriteBase /home/main/public